# Using a searchbox and a webgrid on the same page, what model should the page be based on?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Just starting out in ASP.NET MVC - I have a page in ASP.NET MVC3 that has a searchbox, and when the user fills it out and searches, below the search box a webgrid shows the searchresults.

I have based my (razor) view on a model `List<articles>` so the view knows what an article is and my webgrid can show me a list of articles. However, I also need the searchbox to be validated. I have a "searchmodel" that has the searchbox as a required field, but I can't base the view on both the List of articles as well as the "searchmodel" (can I?).

Ofcourse I would like the built-in (clientside and serverside) validation of MVC to work, but to do that I would need to base the view on my "searchmodel" and the gridview would no longer work.

Can anyone explain how I would go about this?

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Search { get; set; }

    public List<articles> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

Now strongly type your view to `MyViewModel` and have your controller action pass an instance of this new view model to the view instead of simply a `List<articles>`. This way you have everything.

Comment: Thanks Darin, it seems to be the way to go; but I'm struggling now on the page itself; Before, I could just check `if (Model != null)` in the view to determine wether or not to display the webgrid, but I cant get 'if (Model.Articles != null)' to work. It keeps complaining an object is set to NULL.  As soon as I verify it works I'll mark your answer.

Comment: @Rico Suave, in your controller action you need to pass an instance of MyViewModel when returning the view: `return View(myViewModel);`